# method=flickr.photos.search not working

Tags: javascript, flickr

I am using the flickr API to get photos relevant to my weather info, however the code only sometimes works. Sometimes the background will load with suitable photos however sometimes nothing will load, when i change the method to flickr.photos.getRecent it loads up images however they are not the suitable weather ones which the search method brings up, has this happened to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug on their side. Even the search on the Flickr website doesn't return results when this happens.

https://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157637322588906/
and
https://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157637221802585/

Guess I'll have to implement a fallback to some other service for image search.